# How can I control where enemies place troops?

Tags: clash-of-clans

What effects the line around your property that troops have to be out outside of?  Somehow people are placing troops inside my fencing? How?

Comment: Can you post a picture of your setup?  It will be easier to help you for this.

Answer (score 10):

As jco mentioned, too much space between your structures (including walls) will cause a gap.   **If you move any structure (doesn't have to be in edit mode), you will see a white light outlining your base.   Troops cannot spawn in this area.**

I moved a structure to see the property line and noticed where a gap was:
[image]

After filling the hole (normally I have my archer tower there, but this just for demonstration): 
[image]

If the gap is 2 squares or greater, troops will be able to spawn here.

**Note:  Traps do NOT fill those gaps.**

Comment: Any reason for the -1 ?

Answer (score 3):

Too much space between your structures (more than 2 squares) will cause a gap which can allow enemy troops to be placed inside.  Try moving structures closer together or fill any gaps.  I believe edit mode will show you these gaps.

Answer (score 3):

Enemy troops cannot spawn within 1 space of your buildings except for traps (this includes hidden tesla.) Your walls have a gap on the middle of them 1 space from your walls. To fix this simply re-arrange your setup to include no gaps.