# Opponents giants bypassing my walls

Tags: clash-of-clans

Recently while watching the replays of other players raiding my village I've noticed their giants are just dropping into the middle of my village without breaking through my walls. I've seen goblins doing this too, how are they doing this?

Comment: Pretty sure you did not use the proper tags here. Neither XCom nor Diablo 3 fit here! Please specify which game you are talking about, otherwiese it will be difficult to get an answer.

Comment: id' love to play xcomablo-3 with giants

Comment: Sorry....I fixed it

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I control where enemies place troops?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/153089/how-can-i-control-where-enemies-place-troops)

Answer (score 5):

If your walls aren't very close to any other buildings than that's totally possible. There is a single space around each building/wall that keeps things from being deployed next to it. You can place buildings up to 2 squares away from each other and prevent placement, any farther away and your enemies will be able to deploy right in your base rendering your walls useless.

Example:

```
   OK       OK     NOTOK
 WWWWW    WWWWW    WWWWW
 -----    -----    -----
 -BBB-    -----    -----
          -BBB-    -----
                   -BBB-
```

The third line after the wall in the second example would be available for deployment. When you are in placement mode, there is a highlight around each building/wall that shows it's protected area, any location that is not highlighted is available for deployment.

Answer (score 0):

There is a one-layer padding around your buildings and walls. If your village is not tight, players can spawn troops in between your buildings. Fill in the empty space.

Answer (score 0):

I noticed something when an opponent attacked me, and his giants spawned inside.  They spawned right on top of where I had placed a nation's flag. I'm assuming a flag within your walls will allow enemy attacks to spawn inside your walls.

I moved any flags to the outside, along the gaming borders.  I'll see how this works.